# Taking a Base64 Encoded Image and Sending it with ExpressJS as an Image

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image, http

I'm working on a Node.JS application that utilizes ExpressJS as a web server.

I want to set up a route `/get/thumbnail/by_guid/:guid` that will return an image as a real image, not a base64 string, so I can set up the source of an image tag using `<img src="/get/thumbnail/by_guid/ABCD" >` and the actual image will display.

I'm storing the thumbnails as BLOBs in my database and am retrieving them. When I retrieve them, they become buffers in my node application. I'm then sending those buffers in my route as shown below, where `img` is a buffer object that contains the image.

```
router.get('/get/thumbnail/by_guid/:guid', function(req, res){
    image_helper.guidToImage(req.params.guid).then(function(img){
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        res.set('Content-Length', img.length);
        res.end(img, 'latin1');
    }, function(err){
        res.err(err);
    });
});
```

`guidToImage` returns the image as a buffer.

When I go to the url described by a thumbnail I know at, for instance, `/get/thumbnail/by_guid/ABCD`, I see a white box like this:

[image: White Box]

When I look in the network tab of chrome dev tools, the request looks like this:

[image]

The response just shows my base64 string:

[image]

And the image shows as broken when I source it:

[image]

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

I've spent 6 hours trying to get this working right now.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how do you display the image in HTML?

Comment: @Jorg exactly like I posted: `<img src="/get/thumbnail/by_guid/ABCD" >`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. If the source is base64, you'll need to specify: `src="data:image/png;base64,[your base64 code]...`

Comment: How about using `atob`?

Comment: @Jorg, I know I can display it that way, however I want to source the image as if it were an image file, I don't wish to base64 embed the image. Is there a way I can do that? Your method would require me to asyncrhonously load the base64 of the image into the src attribute of the img element.

Comment: @Phil, what do you mean?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/atob

Comment: try `res.end(img, 'binary');`

Answer (score 5):

Changed route to get the binary to show properly.

```
router.get('/get/thumbnail/by_guid/:guid', function(req, res){
    image_helper.guidToImage(req.params.guid).then(function(img){
        var im = new Buffer(img.toString('binary'), 'base64');

        res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
        'Content-Length': im.length
        });
        res.end(im);
    }, function(err){
        res.err(err);
    });
});
```